# PHP preg_replace_callback variables optimization

Tags: php, variables, optimization, preg-replace-callback

I've been searching a lot on info about preg_replace_callback and managed to get my thing to work, but I'm wondering if this can be optimized?

Can I run these two in a single preg run?

```
  // 1. replace [date xx] with event date in "xx" dateformat

$output = preg_replace_callback('/\[date (.*?)]/', function($matches) use($eventDate)
          {
              return date($matches[1],$eventDate);
          }, $output);


  // 2. replace [title], [venue] and [link]

$replacePattern = array( '/\[title\]/',
                         '/\[venue\]/',
                         '/\[link\]/');

$replaceReplacement = array($eventTitle, $eventVenue, $eventLink);

$output = preg_replace($replacePattern, $replaceReplacement, $output);
```

Comment: You could combine them, but that won't make your code any better. You don't even need `preg_replace()` to do the latter...`str_replace()` works just as well and is a way better choice.